# Deleting Node from BST, multiple errors with Delete function, rest of code Compiles without it

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes

So i'm very much so stuck on my delete function. I keep getting about 20 errors throughout and several are different ones. When I delete the entire thing from my code though, it compiles, so I know it's only this that is missing and messing up my code, but I also really need it in my code of course! here's the delete function and I'll also list my node Class under it as well

```
public Node delete(Node t, int key){
        if (t == null){
            return t;
        }
        else if (key < t.getKey()){
            t.getLeft() = delete(t.left, key);
        }
        else if(key > t.getKey()){
            t.getRight() = delete(t.right, key);
        }
            else{
                //Deleting a node with no subtrees
                if (t.getLeft() == null && t.getRight() == null){
                    t = null;
                    t--;
                }
                //Node only has one subtree
            else if(t.getLeft() != null && t.getRight() == null){
                t = t.setLeft();
                t--;
            }
                //Node only has one subtree again for opposite side
            else if (t.getLeft() == null && t.getRight() != null){
                t = t.setLeft();
                t--;
            }

            //Finding minimum in the right side, and replace
            else if (t.getLeft() != null && t.getRight() != null){
                temp = t;
                if (t.getRight().getRight() == null && t.getRight().getLeft() == null){
                    temp = successor(t.getLeft());
                }
                else{
                    temp = successor(t.getRight());
                }

                t.key = temp.key;

                if (t.getRight().getRight() == null || t.getLeft().getLeft() == null){
                    t.setLeft() = delete(t.left, t.key);
                }
                    else{
                        t.setRight() = delete(t.right, t.key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    public Node successor(Node t){

        while (t.getLeft() != null){
            t = t.left;

        }
    }
```

Here's my Node Class for reference to some of the functions like getLeft() and so on:

```
public class Node{
    private Node next;
    private String name;
    private int ssn;
    private int key;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;


    public Node(String name, int ssn){
        this.name = name;
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public Node getRight(){
        return this.right;
    }

    public Node getLeft(){
        return this.left;
    }

    public void setRight(Node p){
        right = p;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node p){
        left = p;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n){
        this.next = n;
    }

    public int getSSN(){
        return this.ssn;
    }

    public int getKey(){
        return ssn%10000;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setSSN(int ssn){
        this.ssn= ssn;
    }
}
```